# Ingress Routing to different k8s service for sub domains

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to create an ingress that routes to **service1** when **service1.domain.com** is entered & **service2** when **service2.domain.com** is entered.
My ingress file looks like this below.
I am on Azure AKS and using Azure App gateway as my ingress controller. Below is how my ingress yaml looks like.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - host: service1.domain.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: Prefix      
  - host: service2.domain.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: Prefix
```

However, both the domains are getting routed to service2. Can someone help what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec look wrong. It should be:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - host: service1.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: Prefix      
  - host: service2.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: Prefix
```

There should be two items in your rules, one for each subdomain. `http` and `host` are two fields of the same item.

Comment: silly mistake. I was scratching my head out over this. I feel silly. Thanks Dude.